# Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

I was wondering if someone can point me out a reinforcement learning algorithm/paper (continuous variable), in which the Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo has been directly used. Thanks!